# angular-cli not working on internet explorer 11

Tags: asp.net, angular, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on a project based on Angular-cli the latest version and IIS 7.

After `ng build --prod` and deployed the project to IIS I'm getting errors on Explorer 11 only:

> SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
>
> inline.c2fbd6f28d9028d0f2d2.bundle.js (1,1270)
>
> SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number
>
> polyfills.9af16567db3cf16c3470.bundle.js (1,2727)
>
> SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
>
> main.d8b24e3cf35883ac1c99.bundle.js (1,63930)

My `polyfills.ts`:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/client/shim';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following to support `@angular/animation`. */
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/** ALL Firefox browsers require the following to support `@angular/animation`. **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/***************************************************************************************************
* Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
*/
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.

/***************************************************************************************************
* APPLICATION IMPORTS
*/

/* polyfill ie11 */
import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

/**
 * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
 */
// Run `npm install --save intl`.
import 'intl'; 
import 'intl/locale-data/complete.js';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en.js';

if (typeof SVGElement.prototype.contains == 'undefined') {
    SVGElement.prototype.contains = HTMLDivElement.prototype.contains;
}
```

Comment: In the `apps` section of `.angular-cli.json`, do you have `"polyfills": "polyfills.ts"` set? And in `tsconfig.json` what is your compile `"target"` set to?

Comment: In angular-cli.json i have  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts" set and in tsconfig.json the complile target on es5

Comment: And compile target?

Comment: Also, what is your `ng v`? (The whole Angular kit is updated pretty regularly.)

Comment: Angular CLI: 1.5.0
Node: 8.9.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.0.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.5.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.32
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.20
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.35
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.1
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.8.1

Comment: I'm also getting 2 errors of SCRIPT5011: Can't execute code from a freed script
zone.js (2747,17)

Comment: Third time's the charm: what is your compile target?

Comment: compile target = es5